# hiring or deployment

Tags: meaning

Can I use hiring in this context?

> I improve the work prossess by hiring the communication technologies.

or

> I improve the work prossess by deployment of communication technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Deployment* ([The relocation of forces and material to desired operational areas](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deployment?s=t)) is better here. [Hiring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hiring) implies you are paying to use the technology for a limited time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both of these are technically valid as used, but neither is a great option. Hiring has strong connotations with personnel rather than techniques or methods, and while deployment, in this context, *can* be used to convey the idea of the usage or utilization, it does so awkwardly. Perhaps you are looking for "by employment of"?

But if it's one or the other, deployment is more apt.